# How to change content hash value, within the_block_template_skip_link action?

Tags: filters, actions, accessibility

When my WordPress site loads up, towards the top, I have something that is generated in the DOM....

```html
<a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content">Skip to content</a>
```

From my child theme, what action or filter can I use to change the href value from `#content` to something like `#content-top`?  Having trouble to finding resources online that talk about making this adjustment...

I tried the following just to see if it goes away as a test...

```php
 remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'the_block_template_skip_link' );
```

But that has no impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'the_block_template_skip_link' )` did not work, then try with `remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_enqueue_block_template_skip_link' );`, or both of that. [(see source on GitHub)](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.4.0/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L719-L720)

As for changing the `href` value, I'm not aware of any (filter) hook to do that, but you can either edit your template and set the `<main>`'s `id` value to `content-top`, or you can use JavaScript to modify the `href` value. E.g.

```js
document.querySelector( 'a.skip-link[href="#content"]' ).href = '#content-top';
```

Comment: The JavaScript approach ended up being the only way to work for me. Many thanks for breaking out multiple options.

Answer (score 0):

`the_block_template_skip_link` function is a part of the WordPress block editor and is responsible for generating the `Skip to content` link in the HTML output. To modify the href value of this link, you can use the `the_block_template_skip_link` filter.

For more detail visit :- **[the_block_template_skip_link()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_block_template_skip_link/)**

Add code to your child theme's `functions.php` file

```
function modify_block_template_skip_link($output) {
    // Replace the href value with your desired value, e.g., #content-top
    $output = str_replace('href="#content"', 'href="#content-top"', $output);
    return $output;
}

add_filter('the_block_template_skip_link', 'modify_block_template_skip_link');
```

Comment: The idea is great! But this as an actual process, does not work.